# Find: Reference to Current Directory

Tags: find

I'm trying to use `find` with the `regex` option. However my regular expression only captures the basename of the file. Is there a reference to the "directory find is currently in" I can use in my regular expression so that I don't have to account for it by means of a leading `.*`?

(I'm looking for something like the `$File::Find::dir` in `perl`'s `File::Find` module.)

As an example: suppose I want to find all files matching the regular expression `baz\d` anywhere below `/foo/bar/`. Using `find /foo/bar -regex 'baz\d'` won't find a file named `baz1` at `/foo/bar/` because the pattern `baz\d` doesn't match the full filename `/foo/bar/baz1`, so instead I'm using `find /foo/bar -regex '.*baz\d'` which works, but I'm wondering whether I can replace that `.*` with something more robust?

Comment: Is this in shell scripting? And can you post the lines you're using now and some example of what you would try to accomplish? The example should make it more clear.

Comment: @gertvdijk: do you know of another category using `find` may fall under?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "anchor" the beginning of the filename by including a slash in the regex pattern:

```
find /foo/bar/ -regex '.*/baz\d'
```

This will ensure that you only get files like `baz1`, and not `bazbaz1`.

Comment: I guess that's the best we can do.